# maven release plugin : Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, artifactory, multi-module

I am trying to use maven release plugin to make a release of my multi-module project. when i execute

mvn release:prepare

i get following error

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project sample-packt-serverside: Execution defau
t-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
```

then i tried to execute

mvn -e -X release:prepare

then i see the following output on the console

could anybody help me to resolve this isssue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the trailing letter `s` in `groupId` of the plugin. Correct declaration should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'd also consider upgrading to a fresher version. As far as I can see, current version is 2.4.1.